# check/uncheck w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following function that checks/unchecks all checkboxes on the page by selecting one

```
$("#checkall").click(function() {
    var checked_status = this.checked;
    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        this.checked = checked_status;
    });
});
```

I need to modify it in such a way that if all are selected by clicking checkall and then one is unchecked the #checkall gets unchecked as well. Or do I need to create a separate function for this?

Also when NONE of the checkboxes is selected I need to add a class to another element.

```
$("#myElement").addClass("disabled");
```

Putting it all together sort of complicates things for me.

Comment: Yes, just put an event on each checkbox. Also, the each loop is unnecessary in the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use change event.

Is this what you are after?:

```
<div class="checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkall">
</div>
<div id="list">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
var checkboxes = $(":checkbox", "#list").change(function() {
        var allIsChecked = checkboxes.length === checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;

        checkAll[0].checked = allIsChecked;
});

var checkAll = $("#checkall").change(function() {
        checkboxes.prop("checked",this.checked);
});
```

demo (if you are using jquery 1.6+): 
http://jsbin.com/ezofal/edit

added the #MyElement class toggle in this link: http://jsbin.com/ezofal/2/edit

Comment: If im not misstaking prop came in 1.6, but if you are running an older version just change .prop to .attr insteead.

Comment: +1 for using the `change` event.  Clicking a checkbox is not the only way to check it.

Comment: Cool. BTW how do I detect when NONE are selected (end of my question)?

Comment: it does it I have taken the collection of checkboxes and compare them who are checked, if both collections are the same length, then auto-check the "select-all" checkbox. I have added teh #MyEleemnt toggle class if all the checkboxes are checked. if you have some checked on the page load you may want to trigger the change event on a pageload also.

Comment: <strike>Sounds like voigtan's answer is the accepted one (kudos on the use of change) but with regard to detecting if all are checked, my answer addressed that http://jsfiddle.net/N2dH5/2/ </strike> oh nvm then XD

Comment: @Joseph I still can't get it to work... but I do like the simplicity

Comment: @santa if you look at the second link I changed it to 1.5.1 code, may help you on your way ;)

Comment: @voigtan #myElement is a button link and should be disabled when NO checkboxes are checked, the opposite of the current. Sorry, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: just change the javascript/html to make it fit your need ;) like http://jsbin.com/ezofal/3/edit

Comment: Almost there!.. The reason I called #myElement is a button link, because it is actually a link, styled as a button. I know... how more confusing is it going to get? <a href="/myURL" class="btn">Delete Selected</a> I am actually thinking that just adding a class won't do it. I probably need to swap it with a static element, like span: <span class="btn">Delete Selected</span>...  Hey, thanks for your help and patience. :)

Comment: you can use return false/true on links, return true if you want to use the default link, return false to prevent that: http://jsbin.com/ezofal/5/edit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3312/discussion-between-voigtan-and-santa)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkall").click(function() {
        var checked_status = this.checked;
        $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
            this.checked = checked_status;
        });
    });
    $('input[type=checkbox]:not(#checkall)').change(function(){
        if($('input[type=checkbox]').length !=  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length){
              $('#checkall').attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/Toukakoukan/PpaPr/)

Comment: @Santa - You could do this with even simpler code if you put a class on the checkboxes (so you don't have to use the .not() selected to exclude the checkall box)

Answer (score 1):

```
var checked_status = false;
$("#checkall").click(function() {
checked_status = this.checked;
$("input:checkbox").each(function() {
    this.checked = checked_status;
});
});
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
   if(checked_status == true) {
       $('#checkall').checked = false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var checked_status = this.checked;
    if($(this).is("#checkall")) {
        $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
            this.checked = checked_status;
        });
    } else {
        $("#checkall").attr('checked', ($("input:checkbox:not(#checkall):checked").length ==
                                        $("input:checkbox:not(#checkall)").length));
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N2dH5/1/

tested

Some ideas stolen from @Toukakoukan